# Can session be maintained if we turn off javascript in the browser?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, session, cookies

So recently i was asked this question in an interview that "Can you manage session in MVC .NET if javascript is turned off in the browser"?

I replied "Yes we can" but I am not very sure and I need some assistance on this topic.

Answer (score 0):

Sessions, SessionIDs and Session state are managed by the .NET server (by default), not by the client. Turning off JavaScript at the client won't affect the server.

Quote from [MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-2.2#session-state):

> The in-memory [default session state] provider stores session data in the memory of the server where the app resides.

Answer (score 0):

Session is stored on server side and session id is stored on client side, and javascript don't impact the session. So session will work if you turn off the javascript